# Laravel5 - Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel-5

I don't know what is this error. Please someone give me some explaination

on my `UserController.php`

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function viewCard($card_id) {
        return Tag::test($card_id);
    }
}
```

and on my model `Tag.php`

```
class Tag extends Model {
    public function test($card_id){
        return DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT name FROM tagmap tm, tags t WHERE t.id = tm.tag_id AND tm.card_id = :card_id"), ['card_id'=>$card_id]);
    }
}
```

i don't know where it fails, where I do wrong...

thanks....

Comment: Don't you READ the error instead just coping it? :: is call for STATIC method and your method is not static.. :)

Comment: 1. create instance $tag = new Tag(); 2. $tag->($card_id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public function test()` is not a static method. When you try to access a static method with `Tag::test()` it will fail, because.. well the method isn't static.

You have two options:

1) Set your method to static

```
class Tag extends Model {
    public static function test($card_id){
        return DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT name FROM tagmap tm, tags t WHERE t.id = tm.tag_id AND tm.card_id = :card_id"), ['card_id'=>$card_id]);
    }
}
```

2) Invoke it as an instance method by first instantiating your class:

```
$tag = new Tag();
$tag->test($card_id);
```

Comment: but what if it should not  be not static or this class located in some module which should not be changed(like some bundle )