# Non-static method App\User::getallreferrals() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

am trying to call functions inside my model in my controller but i get this error.

> (1/1) ErrorException Non-static method App\User::getallreferrals() should not be called statically. in HomeController.php (line 37)

this is my model.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name','last_name','other_name','user_name','number2','email', 'password', 'number','bank_name','acct_number','acct_name', 'next_kin', 'next_kin_no', 'transaction_details', 'entry_matrix','referral_id', 'referred_by','first_downline_id', 'second_downline_id'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays. `1
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function scopeGetallreferrals($query)
{
    return $query->where('referred_by', Auth::user()->referral_id)->pluck('referral_id');
}

public function scopeGetallreferralsobject($query)
{
    return $query->where('referred_by', Auth::user()->referral_id)->get();
}

public function scopeGetallreferrals2genobject($query)
{
    $referrals = $this->getallreferrals();
    return $query->where('referred_by', $referrals)->get();
}

public function scopeGetallreferrals2gen($query)
{
    $referrals = $this->getallreferrals();
    return $query->where('referred_by', $referrals)->pluck('referral_id');

}

public function scopeGetallreferrals3gen($query){
    $referrals2gen = $this->getallreferrals3gen();
    return $query->where('referred_by', $referrals2gen)->pluck('referral_id');

}

public function scopeGetcaptain($query)
{
    return $query->where('referral_id', Auth::user()->referred_by)->pluck('referred_by');
}

public function scopeGetallcaptain2gen($query)
{
    $captain = $this->getcaptain();
    return $query->where('referral_id', $captain)->pluck('referral_id');

}

public function  scopeGetallcaptain3gen($query){
    $captain2gen = $this->getcaptain2gen();
    return $query->where('referred_by', $captain2gen)->pluck('referral_id');

}

public function  scopeGetallreferralsbyID($query, $id){
    return $this->getallreferrals()->where('id', $id);
}

public function  scopeGetallreferrals2genbyID($query, $id){
    return $this->getallreferrals2gen()->where('id', $id);
}

public function  scopeGetallreferrals3genbyID($query, $id){
    return $this->getallreferrals3gen()->where('id', $id);
}
```

}

then my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\DateTime;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Session;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function index()
{
    $captain = User::getcaptain();
    $referrals = User::getallreferrals();


    return view('home', ['captain' => $captain, 'referrals' => $referrals]);
}
```

Please what am i not doing right? I have been on this project for a while now.

my migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('other_name');
        $table->string('user_name');
        $table->string('number');
        $table->string('number2');
        $table->string('bank_name');
        $table->string('acct_number');
        $table->string('acct_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('next_kin');
        $table->string('next_kin_no');
        $table->string('entry_matrix');
        $table->string('transaction_details')->nullable();
        $table->integer('isconfirmed')->default(0);
        $table->string('total_earned')->nullable();
        $table->string('total_paid')->nullable();
        $table->string('type_account')->nullable();
        $table->integer('stage')->default(0);
        $table->string('referral_id')->unique();
        $table->string('referred_by')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel5 - Non-static method should not be called statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940427/laravel5-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-statically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is saying the getallreferrals method is not static, but you are trying to call it with :, which means static.

It should be something like

use a [Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) for this in User model

```
public function scopeGetallreferrals($query, $user)
{
    return $query->where('referred_by', $user->referral_id);
}
```

and in controller

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{ 
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->user = Auth:user();
}

public function index()
{
    $captain = $this->user->getcaptain();
    $referrals = $this->user->getallreferrals($this->user)->pluck('referral_id');

    return view('home', ['captain' => $captain, 'referrals' => $referrals]);
}
```

Comment: thanks i think that worked. But then a new error arose. FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function where() on null
in User.php (line 52)

Comment: its because may be some time the user is not authorized. need to check for null value

Comment: public function scopeGetcaptain($query)
    {
        return $this->model->where('referral_id', Auth::user()->referred_by)->pluck('referred_by');
    }        
that is the line. It seems the returned value is null. I don't want it to show the error. How will i do so

Comment: @PatrickObafemi see i updated the answer. Check whether it's working now.

Comment: no it's not. Still the same error. When a user does not have a captain it shows the null error but when he does it does not show an error. If a user has no referral it shows the null error but then he does it does not.

Comment: So it means first you need to find the user. Do you want the authenticated users captian and referrals?

Comment: If you want to authenticated users details add this line to the most top of index method $this->user = Auth:user();

Comment: exactly. i want the authenticated users captain and referrals, Though some users might not have a captain or a referral. Those users are returning null. I want to bypass that

Comment: @PatrickObafemi edited.added middleware and assigned it to the user property.

Comment: FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function getcaptain() on null. New error.

Comment: public function scopeGetcaptain($query) {
        return $this->model->where('referral_id', Auth::user()->referred_by)->pluck('referred_by');
    }

Comment: that's the get captain method

Comment: Change $this->model to $query->

Comment: Actually you should create relationships in the model

Comment: okay. you've really been helpful @aimme. Can you just help me with the logic behind the relationship?

Comment: Ok. Can you update your question with your migration files and models.