# Non-static method Mds\Collivery::getTowns() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to use the collivery package with laravel. However when i try use it i get the error in the title. How will I call the class non statically.

This is what i am trying to call.

```
public function getTowns( $country = "ZAF", $province = null )
{
    if ( ( $this->check_cache == 2 ) && is_null( $province ) && $this->cache->has( 'collivery.towns.'. $country ) ) {
        return $this->cache->get( 'collivery.towns.'.$country );
    } elseif ( ( $this->check_cache == 2 ) && ! is_null( $province ) && $this->cache->has( 'collivery.towns.'. $country .'.'. $province ) ) {
        return $this->cache->get( 'collivery.towns.'.$country.'.'.$province );
    } else {
        try {
            $result = $this->client()->get_towns( $this->token, $country, $province );
        } catch ( SoapFault $e ) {
            $this->catchSoapFault( $e );
            return false;
        }

        if ( isset( $result['towns'] ) ) {
            if ( is_null( $province ) ) {
                if ( $this->check_cache != 0 ) $this->cache->put( 'collivery.towns.'. $country, $result['towns'], 60*24 );
            } else {
                if ( $this->check_cache != 0 ) $this->cache->put( 'collivery.towns.'. $country .'.'. $province, $result['towns'], 60*24 );
            }
            return $result['towns'];
        } else {
            if ( isset( $result['error_id'] ) )
                $this->setError( $result['error_id'], $result['error'] );
            else
                $this->setError( 'result_unexpected', 'No result returned.' );

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940427/laravel5-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-statically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create instance of the Collivery class  to access in your controller. You can try the below code

`$config = array(
    'app_name'      => 'Default App Name', // Application Name
    'app_version'   => '0.0.1',            // Application Version
    'app_host'      => '', // Framework/CMS name and version, eg 'Wordpress 3.8.1 WooCommerce 2.0.20' / 'Joomla! 2.5.17 VirtueMart 2.0.26d'
    'app_url'       => '', // URL your site is hosted on
    'user_email'    => 'demo@collivery.co.za',
    'user_password' => 'demo',
    'demo'          => false,
);`

```
$collivery = new \Mds\Collivery( $config );

$towns = $collivery->getTowns();

dump( $towns );`
```